# Do we Draw a Line at Books?

Tags: discussion

I'm a bit puzzled, and it might be just a random coincidence, but a recent [question about a book](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/29743/6659) did get an almost instant downvote.

Given, there is no close request, but to me the question does not fulfil the required 'unclear/missing research/not useful' criteria. It seems well written, with a good number of details, even including a picture of he image the author remembers from that book's cover. Over all, way better supported then many other 'identify-something' questions.

And yes, it's only one downvote, but I couldn't halt to think that someone doesn't like a book being searched and since that topic hasn't come up so far, I'd like to ask:

**Do we welcome book questions?**

*(Them being within the usual margins - like related to old computers and within historic context - of course)*

We seem to accept a lot of quite vague questions even about arcade machines, so I would think book questions, at least when written that clearly, should have their place.

---

[And yes, I know, there are zillions of books, like "how to type in a number in an Excel sheet", one can rightful forget about and should not be remembered at all, but that's not the point]

Answer (score 12):

We already have [books](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books) with 30 questions; many of them are questions about something read in a book, but there are a few book identification questions in addition to the new one which prompted your question:

- [What is the title of this Macintosh programming book?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/4817/79)
- [Were any of the books mentioned in this scene from the movie Hackers real?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/10997/79)
- [What was this book about floating-point system design/construction?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/18041/79)

I think questions about books can be relevant to retro-computing, considering the general idea that we want to help people trying to *use* retro-computers. A lot of relevant information was only available in books, so helping users find relevant retro-computing books is helpful. Of course questions and answers about specific problems are most on-topic, ideally with answers which *don’t* require readers to go and find a book, but given the importance of books and the fact that some topics take whole books to address means that we shouldn’t exclude book questions wholesale.

Books also have a huge cultural place in retro-computing, given their importance back in the day. Changing habits mean that present-day users might not even *imagine* some of the books people relied on in the past, for example the software catalogs as described in [What was the title of this IBM PC software compendium book circa mid 80s?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/29743/79) (I’m thinking of titles such as *DOS Power Tools* which probably seem outlandish today). I think preserving knowledge of how people worked with computers is also worthwhile here.

I don’t mean that we should allow *any* questions about books; questions which are otherwise off-topic shouldn’t be considered on-topic just because they are about books. However even there we probably shouldn’t be as strict as other SEs which cover current topics — in the retro world we *do* have widely-agreed-upon “best” books on a few topics, so even seemingly opinion-based questions might be on-topic. (But that’s arguable, so feel free to disagree with me.)

Answer (score 0):

Frame challenge  :-)

I downvoted, not because it was a book, but because it was yet another "I vaguely remember something, please tell me what I am thinking of" posting.

I find such questions to be "not useful".

Comment: Ok. Works. Maybe I'm already going soft but I thought of it as one of the better ones, but yes, I do quite well understand that position.